# How to execute spark scala script saved in a text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written word count scala-script in a text file and saved it in home directory.
How can i call and execute the script file "wordcount.txt" ?

If I try the command: `spark-submit wordcount.txt`, it is not working.

Content of "wordcount.txt" file-

```
val text = sc.textFile("/data/mr/wordcount/big.txt");
val counts = text.flatMap(line => line.split(" ").map(word => (word.toLowerCase(),1)).reduceByKey(+).sortBy(_._2,false).saveAsTextFile(“count_output”);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Please refer to guidelines on how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Also write your spark submit and the results that you get in order to be able to help you

Comment: Check this link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html. Spark submit dont understand .txt file you should create jar and then submit.

Comment: Read and follow step by step - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: You could also do `spark-shell -i wordcount.txt` or from inside spark-shell you can execute `:load wordcount.txt`